# Why does my script has all red lines when I enter status code in Assertion

Tags: rest-assured

I am new in API testing and writing my first java script. Every thing works fine till I tried to do assertion and put status Code 200. Then whole script got red lines.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class Bases {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        RestAssured.baseURI= "https://maps.googleapis.com";

        given().
            param("input","%2B61293744000").
            param("inputtype" , "phonenumber").
            param("fields","place_id").
            param("key","AIzaSyAPKUY3YgFBlyyQxjh9q9RQ5cDFdDjqlz4").

        when().

            get("/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json").
             then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: `Then whole script got red lines.` finding it difficult to understand what this means.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded jars ver 3.2 and it works now. So I believe we can not use update 
ver 4.1.2.jars.